# service unavailable message

Tags: asp.net, iis

There is a web site, and when user exceed 1000, there is an error which is called

```
Service unavailable
```

And I want to show a text, when the system gives "service unavailable" error. How can I do it?

(app_offline.htm can be used but I want to automize it)

Answer (score 1):

In case you're dealing with ASP.NET, you can create your own html page with your custom text, then configure the web.config file, more specifically the [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) tag, to show that file when a 503 Http code is sent to the client (that is again, assuming that IIS is sending the 503 code to the browser).

Hope that helps.

Cheers.

Comment: <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                  mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500"
             redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

There may be sevaral possible reasons this problem,

- Simultaneous connection may reached the time limit
- Your app pool may not starting properly

There is an interesting article about [One more reason problem that causes the 'Service Unavailable' error from IIS](http://geekswithblogs.net/SabotsShell/archive/2008/05/18/one-more-reason-problem-that-causes-the-service-unavailable-error.aspx), which might give you a better understand.

Answer (score 0):

As you state that you're using ASP.NET you should look at trapping errors using the `Page_Error` event handler.

As this tends to be repeated code both in one project and many other projects, I use a base class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` and fill in the handler there.

For example all pages based on `MyBasePage`

```
protected void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    this.ErrorRedirect(ex, false);
}

/// <summary>
/// Redirects to a custom error page
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ex">the caught exception</param>
/// <param name="errorCaught">true if the error is handled within a try catch block, false otherwise</param>
protected void ErrorRedirect(Exception ex, bool errorCaught)
{
        /* some logging code here for use by support team */

        if (ex.GetType().FullName == "BusinessObjects.BrokenRulesException" )
        {
            Response.Redirect("ContactHelpdesk.aspx");
        }

        if (errorCaught)
        {
            Response.Redirect("ContactHelpdesk.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
        }
}
```

In this code "BusinessObjects.BrokenRulesException" are thrown when my there are issues with user entered Model data that doesn't match specified rules e.g. postcodes, passwords etc. in which case a user help page pops up.

In your case you'd be looking at errors to maybe pop up the Error page.